# Resize section header in UITableView with constraints?

Tags: ios, uitableview, header, constraints, sectionheader

`UITableView` is resized with constraints. It has 2 sections and the second section's header is resized inside `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`:

```
headerHeight = tableView.frame.size.height - rowCount * oneRowHeight;
```

So when the table is resized this header should fill the empty space.

The problem is how to resize this if the table is already shown and constraints are changed later? If I try to get the frame - it returns incorrect value.

**ADDED**

[Picture](https://ibb.co/mr2bHa) of I idea I need to achieve.

I have table from left with top and bottom constraints. Then I change the bottom constraint and it decreases the table height. I want to leave cells with the same size and decrease the size of the section header. How to achieve this?

Comment: can you please show us what you want and what's your output right now?
Your question is harder to understand.

Comment: added additional info with picture. I hope it is enough to understand the question now